# In Python 3.5.3, When I try to run this code it just gives me an error saying, "expected an idented block"

Tags: python-3.5

```
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    try:
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
         print('Your guess is too high')
    else:
        break
except ValueError:
    print('You are only allowed to enter an integer value!')
if guess == secretNumber:
     print('Good job ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
     print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))


print('You took ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
```

Comment: It doesn't "just" give you an error saying that. It tells you exactly which line is indented incorrectly.

Comment: yes, sorry I meant, why is it giving this error on the guess = int(input())?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enter the code in your question properly.

Here is a tip: Copy and paste it, and then put `<code>` before the code, and `</code>` after the code.

The error you got says that you didn't maintain the proper indentation required by Python. Check you indentation in all the lines and you will solve it in no time.

Comment: Has this doesn't really answering the question, isn't suppose to be a comment of the question?

Answer (score 0):

As you added in the comments of your question, the buggy line is after the `try` one. A TRY/EXCEPT block needs to be indented too. https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html

Look at the example carefully because you'll see that all the lines under `try` has to be indented, the `except` line has to be at the same level then the `try` and the stuff under been indented one more.